# how to convert array json data into specific json in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I get a JSON array in jquery and now I want to convert this array json data to specific JSON data. I use a `arr.push` to create this json. Now I want to change **this** format:

```
[
    {
        "question": {
            "QuestionType": "QShortText",
            "Question": "What's your name?",
            "PlaceHolderText": "Placeholder",
            "IsNumericOnly": true,
            "CharacterLimit": 0,
            "IsRequired": true
        }
    },
    {
        "Paragraph": {
            "QuestionType": "QPargraphText",
            "Question": "789",
            "PlaceHolderText": "ytut",
            "CharacterLimit": 0,
            "IsRequired": true
        }
    }
]
```

Into **this** format:

```
{
    "question": {
        "QuestionType": "QShortText",
        "Question": "What's your name?",
        "PlaceHolderText": "Placeholder",
        "IsNumericOnly": true,
        "CharacterLimit": 0,
        "IsRequired": true
    },      
    "Paragraph": {
        "QuestionType": "QPargraphText",
        "Question": "789",
        "PlaceHolderText": "ytut",
        "CharacterLimit": 0,
        "IsRequired": true
    },
}
```

I have tried doing this:

```
arrayJsonModel.push({ question: arrayJson[0] })
```

Comment: We know what you want to do. But what have you tried?

Comment: arrayJsonModel.push({ question: arrayJson[0] }) i try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduce` and spreading:

```js
const data = [{"question":{"QuestionType":"QShortText","Question":"What's your name?","PlaceHolderText":"Placeholder","IsNumericOnly":true,"CharacterLimit":0,"IsRequired":true}},{"Paragraph":{"QuestionType":"QPargraphText","Question":"789","PlaceHolderText":"ytut","CharacterLimit":0,"IsRequired":true}}];
const output = data.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {});
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: nice but how i use this { ...acc, ...curr } within <script> tag i face error

Comment: What error @UmarAsif? Press Run above, it's working fine.